# Obtain rowid of SQL Server View After Update

Tags: view, sql-update, primary-key

Is there a way to obtain the value of the primary key in a materialized view that after I update it?  I'm using VB to update a table and I'd like to return the key of the row I updated so I can use it in subsequent operations.  The view will always contain a single record.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.  It looks like I just need to execute the "Output Inserted.ID" after my update statement.

For example:

```
UPDATE MyDB..MyView Set record_locked=1 OUTPUT INSERTED.Id
```